# Windows Azure App Fabric Cache whole Azure Database Table

Tags: azure

I'm working on Integration project where third party will call our web service in Azure. For performance reason I would like to store 2 table data (more than 1000 records) on to the app fabric cache.

Could anyone please suggest if this is the right design pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how much data this is (you don't mention how wide the tables are) you have a couple of options

You could certainly store it in the azure cache, this will cost though.

You might also want to consider storing the data in the http runtime cache which is free but not distributed.

You choice would largely depend on the size of the data, how often it changes and what effect is caused if someone receives slightly out of date data.

Comment: thank. The data table I'm thinking of caching has 7 columns and 1000 records at the moment. Records may grow with time. Not sure what http runtime cache is....is this supported in azure?

Comment: http runtime cache is supported in azure and in fact anywhere where the full .net runtime is available.  It lives in System.Web.Caching

Comment: How would http runtime cache works when there are multiple instances in azure?

Comment: You are not caching a lot of data.  Each instance can hold it's own cache.  This obviously gets more complicated if you need some kind of event driven cache invalidation mechanism.  It's not that much different to using Azure Appfabric Caching with the local cache option enabled.